# analysis and limits of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

[image]Assuming the function:

$\ y=\frac{x-1}{\ln x} $

when the $x$ goes to zero from positive, it occurs that $y$ goes to zero as well.

I would expect that $y$ goes to zero, in such a way that the more the $x$ approaches zero, the more the velocity of the function decelerates so, it would never reach it.

If I cannot use de l'Hopital, to the derivative of the initial function to investigate that, how could one do it?

Comment: $x\rightarrow 1$, not $x\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{x-1}{\ln{x}}=0$$ because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\ln{x}=-\infty.$$
You can not use Hospital here because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}(x-1)=-1.$$

Maybe it means $x\rightarrow1$? If so, it's smooth.

Comment: sure, for the function itself. I would expect that the function itself approaches the origin, with deceleration. But, i don't know how to see if indeed the velocity get smaller and smaller while approaching